# What was the reason behind changing copy-link edit box behavior?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks, keyboard-shortcuts, sharing

**tl;dr**: *What was the reason for disabling <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> shortcut on text field used for sharing URLs to each question and answer. This change and the force to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> instead seems to me very odd and counterproductive. I am looking for a reasons to understand this change.*

---

Some time ago an edit box that holds permalink to selected question or answer (and the whole "Share" functionality) was changed. The *cut* operation / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> shortcut is no longer supported. Only *copy* operation / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> shortcut is now supported.

For years of using SE I learnt myself a quick combination of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> (cut) / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> (switch tab) / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> (paste). This is no longer working.

In general, way outside SE, I am much more used to actually *cutting* piece of text from source rather than *copying* it. Reasons seems quite obvious:

- When cutting, source text disappears and you can -- without looking at the keyboard -- be sure that you hit the correct combination of keys and it is "safe" to do quick switch to another tab and even quicker paste.
- When copying, source text remains in place and you are not sure, if you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or missed a key, until you look at the keyboard or until you actually try to paste text.

For person that is writing (and copying and pasting) without looking at the keyboard and who is writing at approx. 300 letters per minute these few milliseconds break can do the difference. Especially, if you do dozens of copy-paste operations per minute.

Above mentioned change and the need to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> seems quite odd to my and certainly is very counterproductive. It forces me to change the combination that I've been using for years, semi-automatic. I'd like to understand reasons behind that change.

Comment: Do you mean the share link below the question? It's working for me. What browser are you using? I use Firefox on Windows.

Comment: @GDPR the share box still works, but it used to be an editable text field before, which means you could cut text. Now, there's only copying. Also in FF on Win10 x64.

Comment: @Zoethetransgirl yes, that's what I mean. The copy action still works. The field has just a "readonly" parameter. As I read the question, Ctrl+X does *not* work (see the  tl;dr: "force to use Ctrl+C"). That's what I wanted to inform the OP about.

Comment: I hadn't noticed it until this post but must say I prefer it that way because sometimes before I'd accidentally wipe the text or insert a character and would have to start over, but just a personal preference of course.

Comment: It's not that cut specifically doesn't work - you cannot change the text at all. It's a read-only text input. To be honest I've never used Ctrl+X before nor did it ever occur to me. It seems perfectly logical to have it read-only.

Comment: @VLAZ As I have expressed it in my question, this is unfortunately perfectly illogical for me. Not only, I don't like the idea of changing things that were working perfectly for years (are there any posts here requesting to make this field read-only or is this just a fancy of SE creators?). But, what is the most important -- I have proven (have I?) using examples that making it read-only is counterproductive and slows down the process. I value your opinion, but if this is truly perfectly logical for you then, please, provide some examples, how. Maybe I don't understand something obvious.